# Format array data in table

Tags: python, postgresql

The data are presented in the format:

```
tags_list = [
    ['foo'],
    ['foo', 'boo', 'goo'],
    ['boo', 'zoo']
]
```

I'm writing this data to table:

```
for tags in tags_list:
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO tags_table VALUES (%s);""", (tags,))
```

BUT this way data in table becomes to type `tuple`:

```
(['foo'],)
(['foo', 'boo', 'goo'],)
(['boo', 'zoo'],)
```

while I'm expecting:

```
{'foo'}
{'foo', 'boo', 'goo'}
{'boo', 'zoo'}
```

Is it possible to convert data to normal PostgreSQL's ARRAY view?

Comment: Pass `tags` instead of `(tags,)`.

Comment: Can you put your table structure here ~

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ then I'll get an exception `not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me that you can vary the values inserted into the table. How does this even work? You don't even specify any columns names. I can't see how this would work.

Comment: @FrankAK table contains just one column TEXT[], for testing

Comment: Which `Python-API` for pg you have used?

Comment: @FrankAK psycopg2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simple create a table by follow `sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE contacts (
 id serial PRIMARY KEY,
 name VARCHAR (100),
 phones TEXT []
);
```

I am assume you are use `pydb` and I have create a table like the below show

```
 id | name |    phones    
----+------+--------------
  1 |      | {123,222,33}
```

My python code is just simple insert into one list .

```
import pgdb


conn = pgdb.connect(database='test')


cur = conn.cursor()

lst = ['123','222','33']
cur.execute('insert into contacts(phones) values (%s)', (lst,))
conn.commit()
```

It's work for me! I guess you did not `commit` your cursor or your field type is no right!

Back to your example, i have create a table like yours:

```
CREATE TABLE tags_table(tags TEXT[]);
```

Before run my python code, let check table .

```
test=# select * from tags_table;
 tags 
------
(0 rows)
```

and my python code :

```
#import pgdb
#conn = pgdb.connect(database='test')
#if psycopg2 has used
#try this 
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(database='test')
cursor = conn.cursor()

tags_list = [
    ['foo'],
    ['foo', 'boo', 'goo'],
    ['boo', 'zoo']
]


for tags in tags_list:
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO tags_table(tags) VALUES (%s);""", (tags,))

conn.commit()
```

After run the above code, my table got those result:

```
test=# select * from tags_table;
     tags      
---------------
 {foo}
 {foo,boo,goo}
 {boo,zoo}
(3 rows)
```

I don't really understand why you need to show the result as `{}` but there are a simple way to do this by declare your own `List` type.

```
class MyList(list):
    def __str__(self):
        items = ','.join(self)
        return '{' +'{}'.format(items if items else '') + '}'
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()


for i in d:
    j = MyList(i[0])
    print j
```

and you will got the result as below show!

```
{foo}
{foo,boo,goo}
{boo,zoo}
{foo}
{foo,boo,goo}
{boo,zoo}
```

Comment: when I'm checking table in python script, data type in table is `tuple`

Comment: Yes, python show list with `()` but pg show list with `{}`.

Comment: that's cool but problem is how to fix that behavior in python))

Comment: @AntoshaShmonoff hey，as you expect result ，your maybe expect to covert it to pg style with ｛｝，it is very easy to do it with python but you should know python will be use ｛｝to set type

Comment: and you're right again, sets has no indexes, so they cannot be converted to postgres arrays

Comment: @AntoshaShmonoff hey guy! i have update the answer which maybe you want ~

Comment: it's all about perfectionism and curiosity

Answer (score 0):

Here's some compromise solution:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM tags_table;""")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row[0])
```

¯ \ _ (ツ) _ / ¯